# iPhone simulator sandbox location in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4

Xcode 4 seems to have changed the deployment location of the application data which previously used to be in:
`Users/INSERT_YOUR_USER_HERE/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`

Does anybody knows where is it now?

Thanks,
Raj

PS: I am beginning to hate Xcode 4! Sick!!!

Comment: cannot find it, looked all over, apple sux

Comment: found it, it is hidden, the whole Library folder is hidden, unhide all on your mac and you will find it. It is really dumb of them to hide this folder, dont you think? How do you like them apples.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Application is Sandboxed in the location you specified is correct.

```
/Users/INSERT_YOUR_USER_HERE/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/
```

That is this is the place where the Application(.app file) the installation file will be there.

I was wondering that you were searching for the build file or the binary file(.ipa). In Xcode4 they have changed it. Previously in Xcode 3 versions the build file will be in the folder where you have created your Project along with all your .h and .m files.

Now the build file is in this Path

```
/Users/YOURUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YOURPROJECTNAME_SOMETHINGSOMETHING/Build/Products
```

EDIT: More simple solution would be In the left side Navigator window in the Project structure under the Products Folder you will find your app. Right click on that and select open in finder will you take you to folder containing your app .app file.

If you want .ipa file just drag and drop the .app file into itunes it will convert that into itunes file and again rightclik and show in finder will give you the ipa file

Comment: Ok, fine the sandbox location is the same. Well the iPhone simulator's device version was not changed and hence there werent any applications in version 4.3! Well, the build file path did help me, anyways! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On my mac the folder never changed.
The sandbox of each application i have in the simulator can be found in:

```
${HOME}/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<SDK_VERSION>/Applications/<GUID>
```

Comment: Aye, that's where apps are sandboxed in my system. A trick you could use is using the following command in the terminal: `find ${HOME} -name <APP NAME>`. This is how i found mine.

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on YOUR_APP_NAME.app file in xcode, it will take you to the sandbox folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can find that in the following path:

> /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Your-Project-Name/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/location.app